# Broadcast Receiver Priority and Aborting a Broadcast

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am beginner of android.I searched many web-site.But I can not understand this topic.Please tell me why and how and when use **priority & aborting**  in a BroadcastReceiver.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) :

> There are two major classes of broadcasts that can be received:
>
> - **Normal broadcasts** (sent with Context.sendBroadcast) are completely
>   asynchronous. All receivers of the broadcast are run in an undefined
>   order, often at the same time. This is more efficient, but means that
>   receivers cannot use the result or abort APIs included here.
> - **Ordered broadcasts** (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are delivered to
>   one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in turn, it can
>   propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can completely abort
>   the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other receivers. The order
>   receivers run in can be controlled with the android:priority attribute
>   of the matching intent-filter; receivers with the same priority will
>   be run in an arbitrary order.